# ArrayAdapter Failing with Nullpointer Exception using Fragments

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, picasso

I am creating a Popular Movies app from the Udacity course where I am loading images with Picasso using a fragment. The adapter seems to traverse once inside the getView then crashes with a null pointer exception. I have read numerous of other posts but none seem to help me with my problem. I am not sure what is causing the exception. I have already checked and made sure the array list is getting populated. When I debugged the app, The debugger entered into the adapter once and then crashed after the return statement.

My Adapter: MovieArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final String LOG_TAG = MovieArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mValues = new ArrayList<String>();

public MovieArrayAdapter(Context context,int layoutResId, ArrayList<String> values){
    super(context,layoutResId, values);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mValues = values;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView= convertView;

   if(rowView == null){

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_detail, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.movie_imageView_left);

    String url = getItem(position);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "url string: " + url);

    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(url)
            .fit()
            .into(imageView);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mValues.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

My Fragment: DiscoveryActivityFragment.java

public class DiscoveryActivityFragment extends Fragment {

```
private final String LOG_TAG = DiscoveryActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> movies = new ArrayList<String>();

public DiscoveryActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    GridView movieListView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.moviesGridView);
    createMoviesArray();
    mMovieAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(
            getContext(),
            R.layout.movie_list_detail,
            movies
    );
    movieListView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

private void createMoviesArray() {

    movies.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92//vlTPQANjLYTebzFJM1G4KeON0cb.jpg");
    movies.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92//AjbENYG3b8lhYSkdrWwlhVLRPKR.jpg");
    movies.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92//vlTPQANjLYTebzFJM1G4KeON0cb.jpg");
    movies.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92//5BGjNYVHWynVNIbo3eF6XhPeB1J.jpg");
    movies.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92//slobKil2T1ASQbItglLdGfAHJqC.jpg");

   /* movies.add("apples");
    movies.add("oranges");*/
}
```

}

My Main Activity: DiscoveryActivity.java

```
public class DiscoveryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.discovery_main);
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new DiscoveryActivityFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_discovery, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.popularmovies.DiscoveryActivityFragment" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/moviesGridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

movie_list_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/movie_imageView_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Log

10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2310)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1061)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
10-12 19:59:21.264 10526-10526/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That post doesn't help me. and it is not a duplicate of my question

Answer (score 0):

I needed to return rowView and not contextView in the getView method of my ArrayAdapter. I was doing all the work in the rowView then returning contextView which was still null.